# HTML input="file" accept only from certain paths

Tags: javascript, html, file, input, filepath

I have a web page that allow to upload a file via the basic `<input type=file />` I know that with javascript there's no way to get the full path after selection but .. is there a way to ACCEPT files only from certain paths, as I do with extensions (*.jpg, etc)?

I'm in a Windows systems intranet scenario and for security issues, the file I have to upload cannot be uploaded from any folder but only from a network share that contains read-only files written and authorized by administrators

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there isn't, JS can't interfere the opened Download dialog.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to limit from where your users can choose the files? You can make them select a directory, and then navigate this directory from your scripts, you can even create a temporary file-system that they will be able to eventually store somewhere if they'd like, or that you can keep in the browser's own storage, available even across sessions. Would such solutions fit your needs?

Comment: @Kaiido 
"Why do you want to limit from where your users can choose the files?" for security issues. I need that users get files ONLY from certain paths (plural)
"You can make them select a directory, "
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What security issues? You need to be clear about your use case so that we can provide the most correct answer. In the comments below you say that it's for an intranet, can we then assume you can install browser extensions on all the machines that are connected to that intranet? You really need to [edit] your question with more details.

Comment: Edited. 
for security issues, the file I have to upload cannot be uploaded from any folder but only from a network share that contains read-only files written and authorized by administrators

Comment: We still miss the details on what you can do on the machines that do access your intranet. Can you install browser extensions on all the machines? Or a system firewall maybe? And why can't you simply "fetch" the "network share"'s content? Why does it have to go through the file input?

Answer (score 0):

No. And even if there was, how would you specify those paths for Windows/Mac/Linux systems. What about network attached volumes? You can only "suggest" mime-types/extensions and the file dialog is 100% up to the user.

Comment: It's an intranet application, so I know that I'm in Windows-only scenario

Answer (score 0):

No. That is not a feature that browsers provide.

Nor would it be one that makes much sense in the context of the WWW as local file paths are custom to different systems.

Comment: It's an intranet application, so I know that I'm in Windows-only scenario

Comment: @GLBProject — Browsers are designed to operate in the context of the WWW (hence why I was specific in the second paragraph). They don't invest much in features that are only useful in tightly controlled networks.